# Convert PHP String to Binary for Fwrite

Tags: php, file, encoding

I have no idea how to get this code to work but say I have an example string `\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0007\u0000�`, when I try to fwrite this in binary mode, the first 6 characters are encoded properly, but the last one isn't.

This should be the output of the first (7) bytes: `00 00 01 00 07 00 98`
I get: `00 00 01 00 07 00 EF` instead.

I have next to zero knowledge of encoding, is there anyone here who understands my problem as I don't know how to phrase it as I just have access to the raw data, and I am unsure how to encode it so to get the actual output.

Comment: What do you mean by "write in binary mode"? The `fwrite()` function does not support any modes. And actually what should that mean? A string is a string is a string. You write it into the file. No mode to be seen there...

Comment: Sorry, I meant with fopen, I am opening a file that I want to write this string in its binary equivalent, so the newline character for example would be 0A when viewed in a hex editor

Comment: I still can't follow. What is "the binary equivalent of a string" meant to be? A string is a series of bytes. That does not somehow magically change when getting written. Indeed such a series of bytes can be _interpreted_ different. But that does not change the bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up in asking this question. I fixed the problem now, it was at the Data source encoding it into an UTF-8 value which was not consistent with a byte stream. Then a nice utf8_decode fixed it,